# Where I can learn how to implement the physics of 'Where is my water'?

Tags: android, iphone, box2d, physics

I'm working on a game where the water acts as a property that can be used to solve puzzles and interact with other screen elements and I'm very much interested in learning how they managed to get such a fluid physics interaction.

Can that be accomplished with Box2D using particles?

Comment: By "working on", do you mean programming or playing? If playing, you don't tell us which game, yet you ask us how they do what they're doing. More detail needed.

Comment: C'mon guys, I'm developing a game. I want to know if they approaching the physics using particles with some sort of 'stickiness' attached to it or other approach.

Comment: "I'm very much interested in learning how they managed to get such a fluid physics interaction" - who is "they"?  This question is too open-ended to give you a real answer without writing a huge article on a specific solution that might not apply to all potential game water puzzles.  The question might get more traction if it had more specifics of your existing design and requirements, and was seeking a specific type of algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand why so many votes to close. He just asks about how the fluid simulation is implemented in the game named 'Where is my water' available in the app store

Comment: thank you @MerlynMorgan-Graham I will try to improve on that!

Comment: @Andrew me neither, but the other user offered some guidance and I will try to improve on it.

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, I didn't know there was a game called "Where is my water". I thought it was just awkward writing - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnFFWnwOohk

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham read the title!! they = "Where is my water?" developers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After seeing a video of the game you're talking about (and after being told you were talking about a specific game), I thought a [metaballs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs) simulation might do the trick.

Googling "where is my water metaball", I found a description of how to implement this exact game in a [Ludum Dare](http://www.ludumdare.com/) entry:

http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/?p=104952&preview=true

> Particle simulator would be best but integrating that to game would take some precious time that I didn’t have. So I created a pool and obstacles and hefty amount of small slippery balls with pretty high density. You don’t want any friction, damping and only small amount of restitution.  Radius of one ball is about 0.25m when my full screen size is 48m x 32m.
>
> Simulating lots of dynamic bodies that clamp often to one place is really heavy weight operation. This need to be taken consideration. For this reason I used really inaccurate physic settings. I stepped world with only one velocity and position substeps. Also I fixed physic steps to 30/s.(After competition I noticed 20 would be enough) Always when dealing with fixed time step you want to interpolate or extrapolate position when physic are not stepped but rendering is. I choosed extrapolationing. This is simple to pull of.
>
> RenderPos = PhysicalPos + Velocity * TimeAccumulator

Then they go on to describe that the *rendering* is how to trick players in to believing it is a fluid and not tiny balls.  They use a form of metaballs rendering.

> My method was to render water drops as metaballs with radius twice the physical size of the object. Fastest way to make metaball was just sprite that is opaque at middle and fully transparent at edges with smooth circular gradient.